# Scale. Question involving distance, in a straight line, between one city and another.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In Brazil, the cities of Belém and Palmas are on the same meridian (48º west) and their latitudes are 1º South and 10º South, respectively.

Considering the Earth's radius as 3976.776 miles, the distance between the two cities is approximately:

alternatives:

a) 624.47805 miles
b) 633.79862 miles
c) 416,319 miles
d) 312.5497 miles

The answer is option "a".

What I tried was this:
Each degree of latitude is 69.0405532 miles. So, since it's 1° south to 10° south, I made 10 x 69.0405532 = 690.405532

I did this calculation, however it didn't give the closest possible value of alternative "a".

How do you think the answer could be alternative "A"?

remembering: It is the distance in a straight line between one city and another...

Comment: Note that $10^\circ - 1^\circ = 9^\circ$.

Comment: For those of you wondering why the "approximate" distances are given to 7 or more significant figures, 3976.776 miles is 6400km and 624.47805 miles is 1005 km. (I didn't check the others.)

Comment: The exact answer should be $2r\sin(4.5^\circ)$, which is $624.0284977$. Can't seem to be able to guess how to get $624.47805$, sadly.

Comment: The important thing is to arrive at an approximate value. I just want you to explain to me how to get to that approximate value...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing some accuracy converting from km to miles. Here is the basic idea:

Your radius is 6400 km. The circumference of the earth using these measurements is:
2 x Pi x 6400 = circumference of the globe

No find the ratio of the angle between the cities(10 - 1) to the central angle of the globe (360):

9/360 = 1/40

This tells you that the distance between the two cities is equal to 1 fortieth of the distance around the globe (which you know from the first calculation. So now you  find one fortieth of the circumference:

(1/40) (2 x Pi x 6400) = 320 x Pi = 1005.31 km

round that down and convert to miles it comes out to 1005 km = 624.47805 miles

Comment: Very good, DadFlex! I just have a little doubt...

10 - 1 why?

Comment: one city is at 1 degree and the other is at 10 degrees. Subtracting 10-1 gives you the  angle between them.

Comment: Ah understood! Thank you so much!